# How to link Facebook to Iphone App using Xcode

Tags: xcode, facebook, xcode4.3, xcodebuild

I'm using version Xcode 4.3 .  At this stage I have a very basic App, so I have no conflicting features of elements.

I was wondering does anyone know how to link facebook to the Iphone App using Xcode.  I want a simply Login Feature through the use of facebook.  But have been unsuccessful in finding updated tutorials and becoming increasingly annoyed at broken links.

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why not take a look at Facebook's documentation as a starting point? 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/